# How to create nested node in firebase using ionic?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a shopping list which has a title and list of items. How do i add the title and list of item in the firebase? I have try

```
addItem(title, name){
    this.afd.list('/todoListItems/'+ title).push(name);
  }
```

But, this give me this result

```
"Thor" : {
      "-KyWv2dsYgPPBttcGAMO" : "Thor",
      "-KyWv4jrVMOZcAwofyJ_" : "Dark world",
      "-KyWv7VEXwC961Pig2kN" : "Nine relams"
```

I want like this because i have to share this list to another user, so i must have a unique key of the list.

```
"-KyWv2dsYgPPBttcGAMO" :{
    "Thor" : {
      "-KyWv2dsYgPPBttcGAMO" : "Thor",
      "-KyWv4jrVMOZcAwofyJ_" : "Dark world",
      "-KyWv7VEXwC961Pig2kN" : "Nine relams"
    }
   }
```

I want a unique key generate for the Thor as well, I know there is some doc about it, but it seems that i couldn't find one. somehow. Any help will be great.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do i store nested data in firebase. I could't figure out how it works. I have read the docs, but it was no help.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to construct that JSON with the code you shared. What is `title` and what is `name` in your code? What is the existing JSON before you invoke your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen want try to accomplish is to create a todo list application, and i want to have a unquie key for the every list so i can share to other users. I have accomplish it by creating a new collection making the title and the description the child of the collection, to put the list in a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

When you call push on a reference, it creates a reference to a unique child under that location. So if you want the title to be under the title, you must call `push()` before the title:

```
this.afd.list('/todoListItems').push({ title: title, name: name });
```

Comment: it creates separate node for every item, i just want a single title and the number items i insert under it. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON that you're trying to generate.

Comment: i have include the json format i want. I have created a todo list application in ionic firebase, the user can share the list they have created with their friend. I have created user collection, they can send request and add them as friend. I have the stored the list in the local machine and firebase, so if the user share the list to the friend the list must be store in the friends local machine.